# F# Rx extensions IObservable with concurrent events

Tags: multithreading, f#, system.reactive, reactive-programming

I have the following F# code which uses FSharp.Reactive. The function reactToEvents takes two event sources and produces one source of application states. The application states are then consumed by the UI

```
open FSharp.Reactive

let reactToEvents (initialSettings:Settings) 
            (incomingTweets: ITweet IObservable) 
            (uiActions: UserInput IObservable) :  State IObservable = 
    let initialState = { settings = initialSettings; tweets = [] }

    let tweetInput = Observable.map TweetReceived incomingTweets 
    let userInput = Observable.map UserAction uiActions
    let allInput = Observable.merge userInput tweetInput

    Observable.scan transition initialState allInput
```

In the above function incomingTweets events are produced on one thread while uiActions are produced on the UI thread.

Is it safe to merge the two sources using Observable.merge like I do above?

Is it safe to scan the resulting source using Observable.scan like above?

If this is not correct then what would be the correct approach?

Thanks!

UPDATE 1:

I was hoping that at least Observable.merge doesn't care about the threads.
I found this and it seems to say that they are not safe to use like this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353488.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353749.aspx

"For each observer, the registered intermediate observing object is not thread safe. That is, observations arising from the source must not be triggered concurrently on different threads."

What would be the correct approach then?

UPDATE 2:

This was a confusion. The documentation I was linking is for the functions merge and scan from the namespace Microsoft.FSharp.Control.Observable. This is different than Rx which I was using in my code.So for the real Rx you need to use the library FSharp.Reactive and the functions under FSharp.Reactive.Observable

Comment: I don't think it would be an issue. What thread produces it doesn't matter, the whole point is an observable is an event stream. It doesn't matter if its synchronous, asynchronous, or whatever.

Comment: Actually this is what I expected too for Observable.merge. On the other hand, Observable.scan might be trickier because it has the internal state which is updated from two threads

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it safe to merge the two sources using Observable.merge like I do above?
>   Is it safe to scan the resulting source using Observable.scan like above?

Yes, Rx guarantees that this is safe. However, realize that the *results* will come out on different threads. If you expect to then update a UI element with the result, you need to marshal the results to the UI thread via `ObserveOn` (or the F# equivalent)

Comment: Can you point me to some documentation which states this. The official documentation seems to ignore this aspect: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.linq.observable_methods(v=vs.103).aspx

Comment: There was a document about the "Rx Contract" but I can't find it atm. The core idea of Rx though is that it provides you a sane abstraction of concurrency - you don't have to worry about managing concurrent access at an operator level, the operators themselves do work to guarantee this is safe. The one exception to this are Subjects, which can't be OnNext'd concurrently (you need a lock)

Comment: Just to make sure I understand it, is it true for the scan following the merge?

Comment: Yes, all Rx operators are guaranteed thread-safe in this manner. If you write your own operators, it's on you to make this guarantee true

Comment: And here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353749.aspx what do they mean by "For each observer, the registered intermediate observing object is not thread safe. That is, observations arising from the source must not be triggered concurrently on different threads."  ?

Comment: Wait, the documentation you're pointing me to is **not** Rx, but a separate F# implementation. In this case, what I'm saying may not apply, and it *isn't* safe to do.

Comment: I understand. So I was using Rx correctly from the namespace FSharp.Reactive. While that documentation I was linking is about Observable.merge from the namespace Microsoft.FSharp.Control.Observable which is not threadsafe. Thanks a lot for the answer!

Comment: I believe this http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=205219 is the document that @PaulBetts was talking about. According to Rx contract, the observations should never overlap, however if your IObservable does not follow the contract, there's a special extension method called `Syncrhonize` which is meant to fix this.